# Override installed R package in Azure ML by installation of newer version?

Tags: r, azure, data.table

**Is it possible?**

For example, `data.table` version is 1.9.4, while the current one is 1.11.4. The old one does not have very necessary functions.

Comment: Do you mean Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Comment: Yes. We mitigated this problem by building required versions of R packages under R 3.1.0, and they are installed on Azure ML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We mitigated this problem by building required versions of R packages under R 3.1.0, and they are installed on Azure ML.